# How can i save values in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

i want to know how can i save inputs given by users in the chrome extension. I have already seen other answers to this same question but idk why but i cant do it, so please dont answer with the chrome storage api link, if you can reply with the chrome storage link adapted to my code, thanks. This is the html:

````
     <input type="text" id="html_whook" class="input_whook" placeholder="Webhook">
     <script src="./storage.js"></script>```


this is the js code, i was trying to do it:



window.onload = function() {
    function saveChanges () {
        let valore = document.getElementById('html_whook').value;

        chrome.storage.sync.set({'html_whook': valore}, function() {
            alert(valore);
        });
        
    };
}
````

Comment: Do you get any errors or messages?

Comment: Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: Why is the function `saveChanges` inside a the onload event handler? Also, is that where you want to get the value and save since, the window just loaded and user has not input any value. Also, what triggers the `saveChanges` function? Form `submit` or button `click`? These details are missing so please update your question with details. Also, check your browser console for any errors (mind you as @wOxxOm suggested, popup console is different from page's console).

Answer (score 0):

i kinda fixed my code and now it looks like this, i also changed html, i also dont have any errors on the console but it still doesnt work

````
        let valore = document.getElementById('discord_id').value;

        chrome.storage.sync.set({'discord_id': valore}, function() {
            alert(valore);
        });
        
    };


html:    ```    <img src="LOGOVERO.png" class="image" alt="logo">
        <h1 class="testo">Enter your key:</h1>
        <p><input type="text" class="rounded-input" id="key" placeholder="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"></input></p>
        <h1 class="testo2">Enter your Discord ID:</h1>
        <p><input type="text" class="rounded-input2" id="discord_id" placeholder="Example#0001"></input></p>
    </style>
        <p><a><button class="btn" id="save">AUTHENTICATE</a></p>

    </body> This is just a part of the html```
````